# How to search and replace a value corresponding to a string in a file via sed

Tags: shell, awk, sed, scripting

I've got a variable which i would like to append in a string which I searched in a file. I want to update the value i got from it. Variable is:

```
# foo=$(echo "$(hostname)" | awk -F '-' '{print $NF}')
# echo $foo
spsns
```

Now the string that i searched is:

```
# grep "unifiedlogging.host" /opt/tpa/confd/asr.jvm.opt.d/templates/jvm.opt.tmpl
-Dunifiedlogging.host={{$myHost}}
```

Now; I want to replace the value that i got i.e. {{$myHost}} to {{$myHost}}-$foo
and update it on the file itself. I tried doing it with sed but couldn't figure out. Any help with that please?

Answer (score 0):

You ma use this `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak '/unifiedlogging\.host/ s/{{\$myHost}}/&-'"$foo"'/' file
```

Comment: don't you have to escape the `$` in the `s//` ?

Comment: If `$` is not last character then escaping is not must. But I will escape to make it  less confusing for readers.